# How can I show and hide a single field across my web application through a checked value?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have a field called "FooName" and I have "FooName" in several places across my web application (ASP.NET MVC4). I have a check box that allows me to turn "FooName" on and off across the application. Currently, I have access to the checked value (I can grab the saved value from the database) but I'm not sure how to show/hide "FooName" text display across the application?

Is there a utility class I can use or make? Should I use a regex to parse all my web pages? What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

**I think you are misunderstanding the MVC pattern a bit.**

One of the purposes of MVC pattern is to divide your application into "layers".

- The **Model**-layer which contains "data"
- The **View**-layer which represents the "data" (the Model)
- The **Controller**-layer which handles user input and modifies "data" (the Model)

The **Model** does *not* tell the **View** *how* the data should be presented.
The **View** interpretes the **Model** and presents the data.

This means that the **Model** may contain information about how data the may be presented by using properties or fields. But ultimately it's up to the **View**.

In your case (for example) you may add the property – `Model.DisplayFooName`. But this in itself will not change how your **View** looks because the **View** has not been altered. Your **Model** has a shiny new property that your **View** may use to change the way the data in your **Model** is presented. In essence the **Model** is powerless when it comes to the **View**. Your **View** decides how your **Model**-data should be *presented*, and you cannot make changes only to your **Model**, to change the way the data is presented in the **View**.

**TL;DR:**
Ultimately, changes to your **Model** cannot change how **View** decides to present data in it.

---

**To tackle the actual problem:**

If you have a global setting to toggle the display of your `FooName`, you can create a [`HtmlHelper`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application) to speed up the process of toggling it. Instead of having to write something like...:

```
if (GlobalSettings.DisplayFooName)
{
    <strong>@Model.FooName</strong>
}
```

... every time you want to toggle it,
you can create helper that allows you to just simply write

```
@Html.PrintFooName(Model.FooName)
```

Or even..:

```
@Html.PrintFooName()
```

...since the `HtmlHelper` contains the model-data.

This could be sped up by using Find & Replace.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response but if I have @Html.PrintFooName(), how do I toggle it on and off then? If writing the above, prints the name and not display it at all, doesn't display it at all?

Comment: I provided a link in my answer (see HtmlHelper). You decide what you want your helper to print/not print. :)

Comment: Instead of htmlhelper, can I use a viewmodel with bool property to show or hide "FooName"? What are the limitations of this approach instead?

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a single class that knows about your FooName current display settings. **Your Views should decide to show or not the FooName based on visibility settings provided by your class.**

1. When you build your pages, pass the current true/false visibility
   state of your FooName(produced by that class) into viewBag,
2. Everywhere where you have your FooName rendered have a condition
       that checks the boolean.

Comment: so basically, I have to go to to all my classes that contain FooName and pass FooName into view with conditions. Then go to all my views and change visibility for FooName. That doesn't sound friendly. It's sound a bit redundant.

Comment: No, you need new class called FooName or something similar. Have a property FooName.Enabled. Then based on that property you either display it or not. YES, you will have to refactor your code in either case, but at least have the logic to handle FooName related calculations in one place - the class.

Comment: Ahh I see. That makes more sense. Okay, I'll give it a try. Thanks.